# Is there a way to have both encrypted and nonencrypted host vars?

Tags: ansible

If I encrypt `host_vars/*` files with `ansible-vault`, I don't seem to have a chance to have nonencrypted host vars other than those residing in the inventory file. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[As it turns out](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data), `host_vars`- and `group_vars`-files might be directories in actuality. That is, instead of creating `host_vars/example.com` one might create `host_vars/example.com/vault` and `host_vars/example.com/vars`. All the files residing in the directory are read. Which settles it.

Additionally, [the best practice](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#variables-and-vaults) is to store sensitive variables prefixed with `vault_` in the `vault` file, and reassign them to non-prefixed variables in the `vars` file. Like so:

`vault`:

```
vault_mysql_password: '...'
```

`vars`:

```
mysql_password: '{{ vault_mysql_password }}'
```

That way, you'll be able to find encrypted variables with `grep`, or any similar tool.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a full example, with all of the linkages penciled in. Something I sorely needed while I was nutting this out. Context, context, context.

### Ansible config

Ansible will automatically load this file if it is in the same directory as your called playbook.

```
---
# File: /path/to/playbook/ansible.cfg
[defaults]
inventory   = /path/to/playbook/hosts.ini
```

### Hosts file

This file defines host groups. In this example, only the `local` group is important.

```
---
[local]
localhost ansible_connection=local ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2

[ec2]
xx.xx.xx.xx ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path/to/ec2/keys/key.pem
```

### Playbook to gather ec2 facts about any of my instances with the following attributes:

- in the `ap-southeast-1` region
- tagged with `Name: ec2-go`

The playbook.

```
---
# File: gather.yml
- name: Gather remote EC2 facts
hosts: local
connection: local
gather_facts: False

# Necessary variables for fact gathering
vars:
  params:
    region:           ap-southeast-1

tasks:
  - name: Gather EC2 facts.
    ec2_remote_facts:
      aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_access_key }}"
      aws_access_key: "{{ access_key_id }}"
      region: "{{ params['region'] }}"
      filters:
        "tag:Name": ec2-go
    register: ec2_facts

  - name: Print the id of the first instance tagged with "Name: ec2-go"
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ec2_facts['instances'][0]['id'] }}"

  - name: Print ALL of the ec2_facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ec2_facts }}"
```

### Now for the Ansible Vault MAGIC that arises from the following directory structure

```
/path/to/playbook
  /group_vars
    /local
      vars
      vault
```

Guess what? I made no effort to access any of these files with `vars_files` in my playbook, that's the MAGIC! When my playbook is addressing the host group `[local]`, ansible automatically accesses the `/path/to/playbook/group_vars/local` directory and loads the `vars` AND the encrypted `vault` file if we reference an encrypted var (we'll get to that right now).

### Vars

Notice that we automatically access the encrypted vault file by prepending bare vars with `vault_`. No further action required to link these up. It is idiomatic (best practice) to keep the var names the same, i.e. `myVar` --> `vault_myVar`. The advantage of all this dancing around is that it makes variable names visible (think `grep`), rather than hidden within an encrpyted file.

```
---
# File: /path/to/playbook/group_vars/local/vars
access_key_id: AKIAS_YOUR_MUM_MQTFHA
secret_access_key: "{{ vault_secret_access_key }}"
```

### Vault (unencrpyted)

We encrypt this file with `ansible-vault encrypt vault` and a password. We decrypt with `ansible-vault decrypt vault` or more safely, just edit without decryption with `ansible-vault edit vault`:

```
---
# File: /path/to/playbook/group_vars/local/vault
vault_secret_access_key: youShOuLDnOTtRUstEVEryThInGYoUrEAdOniNtErnET
```

### Vault (encrypted)

$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
36613032373533636330363539653565343463333135633564303036653732616435663462306637
6363383237386461613338626362653465343636366264610a623537393937646635366638393362
65353235653166396565333231336332666135663239386162633862356534393066383265333466
6465373962326662350a613339343234376564373662316234653364386337323130663039313239
35353031393437333463346132643632323865623963373862303539363162326161396464353031
39336334346438396161386365653161653231396430646433613132376233666431663863393066
35343433623563653164353730386339316366656666306265353931393337363937376632396332
32333164393534366337663333626566366134373766373137336366366230613763333939633165
35383432666233656363316630643031366431656261386531326162343035393739653366353462
3930356637616130373033333266393639666233666362313935

### Run the playbook:

You'll need the cmdline argument `-ask-vault-pass` because of that ONE variable that is referenced from the vault.

```
ansible-playbook gather.yml --ask-vault-pass
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply don't encrypt `host_vars/*`, but instead encrypt only variable files that you want encrypted.
This article describes a really nice approach: https://www.reinteractive.net/posts/167-ansible-real-life-good-practices

Essentially what you have are nested/chained variables.

This is your plain text variable file:

```
# var_file
db_password: {{ vaulted_db_passord }}
```

And this is your variable file that you are going to encrypt:

```
# vault_file
vaulted_db_passord: a_super_secret
```

In your playbook you refer to `db_password` and it'll resolve into the encrypted password.
Using this approach your variable *names* are still readable plain text, however variable *values* are securely encrypted.

Comment: The question is not about having variable names nonencrypted. I didn't know that [`host_vars` files might be directories](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29682199/52499), which is not particularly clear from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this ansible feature : http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#best-practices-for-variables-and-vaults

```
group_vars/ 
  san_diego/
    vars.yml  # unecrypted yaml file
    vault.yml # encrypted yaml file
```

Ansible will read automatically vault.yml as encrypted yaml file.

Comment: First, info at the link just indirectly describes the feature, that `group_vars` files might be directories with encrypted and nonencrypted files. The main point is about being able to `grep` all the variables. The feature is described [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data). Second, the question is not about having variable names nonencrypted. Third, what you're suggestion is basically [what I come up with](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29682199/52499) much earlier.