# Ansible: How to encrypt some variables in an inventory file in a separate vault file?

Tags: encryption, ansible, ansible-vault

## The settings

Consider an [Ansible inventory file](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html) similar to the following example:

```
[san_diego]
host1
host2

[san_francisco]
host3
host4

[west_coast]
san_diego
san_francisco

[west_coast:vars]
db_server=foo.example.com
db_host=5432
db_password=top secret password
```

## The problem

I would like to store some of the vars (like `db_password`) in an [Ansible vault](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_vault.html), but not the entire file.

How can a vault-encrypted ansible file be imported into an unencrypted inventory file?

## What I've tried

I have created an encrypted vars file and tried importing it with:

```
include: secrets
```

To which `ansible-playbook` responded with:

```
ERROR: variables assigned to group must be in key=value form
```

Probably because it tried to parse the `include` statement as a variable.

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29636942/949859

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If your issue is to have both unencrypted and encrypted vars files per group_hosts.

You can use this ansible feature : http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#best-practices-for-variables-and-vaults

```
group_vars/ 
  san_diego/
    vars.yml  # unencrypted yaml file
    vault.yml # encrypted yaml file
```

Ansible will read automatically vault.yml as encrypted yaml file.

Update : The solution [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44241343/295716) is also good solution (since Ansible 2.3)

Comment: Meaning that san_diego is a directory, rather than a file?

Comment: Exactly, you can use san_diego.yml or san_diego/vars.yml, that's the same.

Comment: You are looking for this answer! @AdamMatan pls mark it as correct.

Comment: The sited best practices suggest naming the files `vars` and `vault`, sans the `.yml` suffix.  In any case `vault.yml` seems odd b/c it's an encrypted file not a YAML file.

Comment: The contents of the `vault.yml` file should be YAML, with the file itself then vaulted. No different than any other vault-encrypted file.

Comment: I'd argue this is a better solution than the one below as key rotation is easier with file level encryption. In all cases, know the pros and cons of file-level vs variable-level encryption and choose wisely.

Comment: Will this work in a role, in the role's *default* or *vars* directories?  For instance, I'd like `repo_root/roles/my_role/vars/main.yml` to stand in for `vars.yml` above, and `repo_root/roles/my_role/vars/vault.yml` to stand in for `vault.yml` above.  The only difference is that they are not in a group_vars directory, and obviously main.yml is named differently.

Answer (score 127):

Since Ansible 2.3 you can encrypt a *[Single Encrypted Variable](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html#single-encrypted-variable)*.
IMO, a walkthrough is needed as the doco's seem pretty terse.

Given an example of: `mysql_password: password123` (within main.yml)

**Run a command such as:**

`ansible-vault encrypt_string password123 --ask-vault-pass`

**This will produce:**

```
    !vault |
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
66386439653236336462626566653063336164663966303231363934653561363964363833
3136626431626536303530376336343832656537303632313433360a626438346336353331
Encryption successful
```

**paste this into your main.yml:**

```
mysql_password: !vault |
    $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
    66386439653236336462626566653063336164663966303231363934653561363964363833
    3136626431626536303530376336343832656537303632313433360a626438346336353331
```

**run playbook:**

Ie, `ansible-playbook -i hosts main.yml --ask-vault-pass`

**Verify via debug:**

```
- debug:
    msg: "mysql Pwd: {{ mysql_password }}"
```

Comment: As of Aug 2018 this should be considered the correct answer to the stated question above.

Comment: Is there a way that you can decrypt all of the vault values at once without having to copy/paste each encrypted string and run the reverse of encrypt_string?

Comment: what type of formatting is that? is that a newline? does it matter?

Comment: @jouell yeah those are simply newlines with spaces for indents. But doesn't seem to matter. I guess whatever yaml supports

Comment: Does this solution work well when the playbook is committed to git?

Comment: @MartinBjeldbakMadsen how do you mean committed to git? Are you referring to issues with indentation of yml or something? I would hope that whoever is using any playbook including the above, would have it committed to git! But yes, no issues with git commit

Comment: Doesn't this leave the password written in plain text in `history`?

Comment: what if i have encrypted secret1 with different password from secret2, How to run playbook with two different password?

Comment: @letthefireflieslive you should just have a single ansible vault password afaik

Comment: @charlie yah I guess so. Just run `history -c` but really this should be running from an ephemeral pipeline agent such as good or Jenkins etc. But if being run from you local machine then yah `history -c` to clear history

Comment: @wired00 okay makes sense, but, if ran from Jenkins how would you prompt for the password? Perhaps create a password file on Jenkins called `~/vault_password` and use the argument `vault_id @~/vault_password`?

Comment: @charlie I'm more familiar with gocd but you can use credentials in Jenkins I believe https://ryandaniels.ca/blog/ansible-vault-jenkins/

Answer (score 20):

At this time with Ansible 2.3 it's possible to have in a plain yaml both encrypted and unencrypted variables. The format of the variables encrypted is like this:

```
dbServer: PlainDatabaseServer
dbName: PlainDatabaseName
dbUser: PlainUser
dbPasswd: !vault |
      $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
      63633363616165656538656537323835343634633063386137353637646663333939623464666437
      6263383933656635316436313934366564316337623435350a386362613838373363393534383232
      39663162363066313431623466363763356466376538613532333731613538373431623239626330
      6463373238366630360a623566616535376339326431363465663431623462356238636333306663
      6439
```

You can encrypt the variable using a password or a password file with the statement:

```
ansible-vault encrypt_string "dummy" --vault-password-file pass-ansible.txt
```

This statement returns the text shown in dbPasswd variable in the yaml above.

To run a playbook that uses the encrypted variable just add the following var:

```
 ansible-playbook playbooks/myplaybook --vault-password-file pass-ansible.txt
```

Or you can do the same with --ask-vault-pass which ask you for the password when executing the playbook:

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/myplaybook --ask-vault-pass
```

Comment: I think you should also mention --ask-vault-pass, not only --vault-password-file

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks! 

We just use --vault-password-file because we run the playbooks with Jenkins in an automated way and it's simpler for us using a file with the password instead of passing the password via pipes or prompting.

I add your option to the post.

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question!

Comment: Thanks for this solution!  I didn't know this was an option.  I dug in a little more and used this after reading it.  Here's a slightly more verbose blog post I made on it afterward in case anyone wants a fuller example a little too verbose for SO -> https://coding-stream-of-consciousness.com/2019/05/08/ansible-vault-encrypt-single-strings-in-config-files-not-whole-file/.

Comment: Just in case this is useful to anyone, to view an inline encrpted value in a yaml file, I found `yq` very handy: `yq -r '.users[]|select(.name == "fred").password' config.yml  | ansible-vault decrypt --vault-password-file vault-password`. Of course that's an example that will need modifying according to one's own yaml structure. I found out about `yq` [here](https://dev.to/vikcodes/yq-a-command-line-tool-that-will-help-you-handle-your-yaml-resources-better-8j9),

Answer (score 8):

You can do something similar to this.

1. Create a password file (a plain text file with your password on a single line)
2. Create an `ansible.cfg` in your ansible project folder

   ```
   [defaults]
   vault_password_file = <path/to/your/password/file>
   ```
3. Create a playbook file (e.g. `playbook.yml`)

   ```
    - name: my ansible playbook
      hosts: 127.0.0.1
      vars_files:
        - 'vars.yml'
      tasks:
        - name: print secure variable
          debug: msg="my secure variable '{{ my_secure_variable }}'"`
   ```
4. Create a variable file (e.g. `vars.yml`)

   ```
   my_secure_variable: "X_my_secret_X"
   ```
5. Encrypt the variable file (from the ansible project location with the `ansible.cfg`)

   ```
   ansible-vault encrypt vars.yml
   ```
6. Run your playbook (from the ansible project location with the `ansible.cfg`)

   ```
   ansible-playbook -i "localhost," playbook.yml
   ```

You should get output similar to:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i 'localhost,'

PLAY [my ansible playbook] ****************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************

ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK: [print secure variable] *************************************************

ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "my secure variable 'X_my_secret_X' "
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************

127.0.0.1                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Where are the non-encrypted variables stored?

Comment: Ansible is fairly flexible regarding variable placement and order of precedence. See http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable.

If we expand on the previous example, we can (but not limited to) do something like this:

`- name: my ansible playbook
   hosts: 127.0.0.1
   vars_files:
     - 'vars.yml'
     - 'insecure.yml'
     - ...
`
Where insecure.yml is yet another yaml file with vars that simply have not been vaulted.

You can also directly embed vars in the playbook with the `vars:` keyword.

Comment: In other words, this doesn't answer the question, which was "how to encrypt _some variables_".

Comment: @RobinDaugherty do you have some insight that helps clarify your statement? Otherwise to respond to your statement, you place a key/value pair in a clear-text file you wish to "vault". When you run Ansible vault it converts that file into an encrypted key store.

For more info, perhaps RTFM here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#what-can-be-encrypted-with-vault.

Once vaulted, you can access that variable like you would any other, however at rest it is encrypted.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your workflow. You can use a `group_vars` file as per Sebastian Stigler suggestion or if you want to use an inventory file, you can just add another "ini-like" file in an inventory directory and encrypt it.

```
$ mkdir my_inventory/
$ cat >> hosts << EOF
[san_diego]
host1
host2

[san_francisco]
host3
host4

[west_coast]
san_diego
san_francisco
EOF

$ cat >> inventory_crypted_vars << EOF
[west_coast:vars]
db_server=foo.example.com
db_host=5432
db_password=top secret password
EOF
```

Then, use `-i my_inventory/` in your command line, or create a local `ansible.cfg` containing:

```
[defaults]
hostfile = ./my_inventory/
```

and you should be set. Ansible will merge both files at run time.

Use `ansible-vault encrypt my_inventory/inventory_crypted_vars` before committing and you're set.

You probably want a pre-commit hook to ensure that you're not committing unencrypted version of the file. For instance [a pre-commit hook like this](https://gist.github.com/leucos/a9f42e111a8cfc2ebf6e) would do the trick (adjust `FILES_PATTERN` accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

You can use group_vars (see http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

Create a subdirectory in your playbook named `group_vars`.
There you create a file named `west_coast` and put the following entries in it:

```
---
db_server: foo.example.com
db_host: 5432
db_password: top secret password
```

This file can then be converted to an ansible vault.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the variables neither be accessible from other playbook, nor change when another inventory file is specified with the `-i` argument.

Comment: You can also put this file to the global config directory `/etc/ansible/group_vars` instead of the directory `./group_vars` in the playbook (see the link in my answer).

Comment: Doesn't answer the question of some vars within a file being encrypted and some not.

Comment: If you read all the other answers you can see, that it is not possible to do it in an single file.